# Can I get the inverse of an LP basis from a GUROBI model object in Python API?

Tags: python, linear-programming, gurobi, matrix-inverse

Is it possible to get the inverse of  an LP basis the model is solved?

For example, I can get the names of the variables that are in the basis with the following code. I am looking for something similar to the following code.

```
gurobiBasisVarNames=[]
for variable in model.getVars():
    if variable.VBasis == 0:
        gurobiBasisVarNames.append(variable.VarName)
```

Comment: Probably not. Also, note the inverse of the basis matrix is dense (in general). So solvers like Gurobi never form an explicit inverse. Rather they use a sparse LU decomposition.

Comment: Of course, you can extract the basis matrix (with columns for variables and slacks that are basic), and invert this yourself. It should be invertible. The basis matrix should have size `(mxm)` where m is the number of constraints.

Comment: Crossposted here: https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/8130531335697-Can-I-get-the-inverse-of-an-LP-basis-from-a-GUROBI-model-object-in-Python-API-